# Partial Vandermonde circulant determinant expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinants, closed-form-expressions, circulant-matrices

Consider following partial Vandermonde type, circulant matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & 0 & \dots & 0 & x_n\\
x_1^2 & x_2^2 & x_3^2 & \dots & 0 & 0\\ 
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots\\
x_1^n & 0 & 0 & \dots & x_{n-1}^n & x_n^n\\ \end{bmatrix}$.

Is there a closed form expression for this determinant like Vandermonde determinant expression?

Comment: I think your typesetting of the matrix (which seems not to be circulant) is off--it appears you have two more columns than rows.  And can you be more clear about which entries are zero?

Comment: no $x_1$ to $x_n$ variables $1$ to $n$ exponents.

Comment: Every row/column has $3$ non-zero entries.

Comment: so it's not circulant, but a termwise product of the vandermonde matrix $V(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with the circulant matrix $circ(1,1,0,\ldots,0,1)$.

Comment: yes thats what I am meaning here.

Answer (score 2):

The "closest" form you can expect is the well known determinant formula for tridiagonal matrices, which in your case can be written as
$$
\Delta = 
\det 
\left[
\begin{pmatrix}
-x_n^{-n} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -x_1^{n}
\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf T_n \mathbf T_{n-1} \cdots \mathbf T_2 \mathbf T_1
\right]
\,\,\prod_{k=1}^n (-x_k^{k+1})\,,
$$
with transfer matrix
$$
\mathbf T_k = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-x_k^{-1} & -x_k^{-2} \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$